# How can I add an onPress event listener to a drawer navigation item in react native react navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v6

I have a drawer navigation configured in the following way:

```
const CustomDrawerContent = () => { return ( <DrawerItem label="Log out2" onPress={() => logOut()} /> ) }

  const loginStack = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator >
      <Stack.Screen name='LandingScreen' component={LandingScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
      <Stack.Screen name='LoginScreen' component={LoginScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
      <Stack.Screen name='RegisterScreen' component={RegisterScreen} options={{headerShown: false}} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        drawerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white' },
        drawerPosition: 'right'
      }}>

        {!user ? (
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="PublicStack"
            component={loginStack}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          /> )
        :
        (<>
          <Drawer.Screen name='Search cocktails' component={HomeScreen} options={{ header: () => <Header/> }} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Profile' component={ProfileScreen} options={{ header: () => <Header/> }} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Publish a recipe' component={PublishRecipeScreen} options={{ header: () => <Header/> }} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Favorites' component={FavoritesScreen} options={{ header: () => <Header/> }} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Published recipes' component={PublishedRecipesScreen} options={{ header: () => <Header/> }} />
          <Drawer.Screen name='Log out' component={CustomDrawerContent} options={{ header: () => <Header/> }} />

          <Drawer.Screen name='CocktailDetailScreen' component={CocktailDetailScreen} options={{
            header: () => <Header/>,
            drawerLabel: () => null,
            title: undefined
          }} />
        </>
        )}

      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
```

All screens work fine, but I want `Log out` to execute a logout function onPress. As I understand, I can't add this event listener directly on the screen component, so I followed this doc (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#drawercontent) and tried a few different things:

- I created the component `CustomDrawerContent` which is a `DrawerItem`.
- If I pass `CustomDrawerContent` as the component to the `Log out` screen (as the code is right now), when I click on it I get redirected to a blank page that renders `CustomDrawerContent`component, which isn't what I want.
- If I pass  `CustomDrawerContent` as `drawerContent` props to the drawer navigator, like the doc says (example below), all other screens dont render anymore, which is again not what I want.

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent />}>
  {/* screens */}
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

- If I put the drawer item together with the screens inside the navigator, the app throws the following error:

```
useNavigationBuilder.tsx:134 Uncaught Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen', 'Group' or 'React.Fragment' as its direct children (found 'DrawerItem'). To render this component in the navigator, pass it in the 'component' prop to 'Screen'.
```

So how can I add the item to the drawer without 'overwritting' the screens?
Or is there other way to put a simple logout button in the drawer?

Full code can be found here: https://github.com/coccagerman/mixr

Comment: have you find the solutions?

Comment: The question is old, but, I will answer because of this recent comment

Answer (score 0):

To add a logout button to your customer drawer, create a custom drawer.

Here is a full example from a live project.

```js
import { DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { logsout } from '../../utils/helpers';

export function CustomDrawer(props) {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.drawHead}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>
          {user?.lname} {user?.fname}
        </Text>
      </View>

      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} contentContainerStyle={styles.s}>
        <DrawerItem label={'Dashboard'} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('UserDashboard')} />
        <DrawerItem label={'Profile'} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('profile')} />
        <DrawerItem label={'Notifications'} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('notifications')} />

        <DrawerItem label={'Logout'} onPress={() => {
          async function load() { await logsout() }
          load()
        }} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>

      <Image
        style={styles.footLogo}
        source={require('../../assets/logo-dark.png')}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  drawHead: {
    display: 'flex',
    height: 180,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 20,
    paddingStart: 20,
    paddingTop: '22%',
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'poppins-Regular',
    color: 'white'
  },
  s: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingStart: 10,
  },
  footLogo: {
    width: 60,
    height: 35,
    marginStart: 20,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  }
});
```

The `logout` here dispatches a redux action to log the user out. Use your own implementation.

Then use the `customDrawer` in your Drawer Navigator:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import UserDashboard from '../pages/user/dasboard';
import Profile from '../pages/user/profile';
import Notifications from '../pages/user/notifications';

import { CustomDrawer } from '../pages/user/customDrawer';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const UserStack = () => {

  const pages = [
    { name: "UserDashboard", comp: UserDashboard },
    { name: "profile", comp: Profile },
    { name: "notifications", comp: Notifications },
  ]

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName='UserDashboard'
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        activeTintColor: '#8772BC',
        headerShown: false,
      })}>
      {pages.map(page =>
        <Drawer.Screen
          key={page.name}
          name={page.name}
          component={page.comp} />
      )}
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
};

export default UserStack;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my working solution in [German Cocca's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14503561/german-cocca) first link in his question, from this [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.3.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.3.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.2.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.6.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.2.1&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fcustom-drawer-content.js)

```js
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList, DrawerItem } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

    const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
        return (
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <DrawerItemList {...props} />
                <DrawerItem label="Logout" onPress={() => handleLogout()} />
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        );
    }

    const ProductListWithDrawer = () => {
        return (
            <Drawer.Navigator
                initialRouteName="ProductList" 
                useLegacyImplementation
        // **** LINE BELOW ADDS Your Custom DrawerItems TO THE DRAWER SCREEN LIST *****
                drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}                
            >
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        );
    };
```